# Outlook click link event?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

So I found a cool little program that asks the user, after they click on a link in Outlook, if they would actually want to visit the site. This program isn't a VSTO or Office add-in. It's call *Second Chance* by KnowBe4.

My question: How would I go about making something like this? I'm not quite sure where to start. As far as I've researched there is no such thing as a windows link click event, but there is child process creation event. I've looked into global hooks and little bit into custom URIs but not sure if any will get the job done. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I basically want to man-in-the-middle link clicks in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

If `ShellExecute` is used to launch the link, you can patch the function using a library like [Detours](https://github.com/citronneur/detours.net).

Comment: Cool repository, Dmitry! Have never seen it before.